# How to write a query with multiple LIKE clauses?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE title LIKE '%samsung%' 
OR title LIKE '%42%' 
AND price >= '100' 
AND price <= '1000000' 
AND shipping = '1' 
AND sale_type = '1' 
LIMIT 0,50
```

The problem is that when i run the query with 2 or more `title LIKE '%%'`it shows me only the ones with the `title LIKE '%%'`

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE title LIKE '%samsung%' 
AND price >= '100' 
AND price <= '1000000' 
AND shipping = '1' 
AND sale_type = '1'
LIMIT 0,50
```

Ignoring the other options. But if I run the query with just title LIKE '%%' it works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this way:

```
WHERE title REGEXP 'samsung|42'
```

More info here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,392332,392950#msg-392950

Comment: Thanks this was the easier and fastest way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE (title LIKE '%samsung%' OR title LIKE '%42%')
    AND price >= '100' 
    AND price <= '1000000' 
    AND shipping = '1' 
    AND sale_type = '1' 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Answer (score 2):

your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE price >= '100' 
AND price <= '1000000' 
AND shipping = '1' 
AND sale_type = '1'
AND (title LIKE '%samsung%' OR title LIKE '%42%') 
LIMIT 0,50
```